# How do i change string to HH:mm:ss only in spark

Tags: string, date, apache-spark

I am getting the time as string like 134455 and I need to convert into 13:44:55 using spark sql how can we get this in right format

Comment: using python or scala?

Comment: Please add more details to the question. Which API are you using? The data that you provided is part of a dataframe or rdd or a file? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: pyspark, the data is being read from parquet file

Answer (score 0):

You can try the regexp_replace function.

```
scala> val df = Seq((134455 )).toDF("ts_str")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ts_str: int]

scala> df.show(false)
+------+
|ts_str|
+------+
|134455|
+------+


scala> df.withColumn("ts",regexp_replace('ts_str,"""(\d\d)""","$1:")).show(false)
+------+---------+
|ts_str|ts       |
+------+---------+
|134455|13:44:55:|
+------+---------+


scala> df.withColumn("ts",trim(regexp_replace('ts_str,"""(\d\d)""","$1:"),":")).show(false)
+------+--------+
|ts_str|ts      |
+------+--------+
|134455|13:44:55|
+------+--------+


scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val df = Seq("133456").toDF
+------+
| value|
+------+
|133456|
+------+

df.withColumn("value", unix_timestamp('value, "HHmmss"))
  .withColumn("value", from_unixtime('value, "HH:mm:ss"))
  .show
+--------+
|   value|
+--------+
|13:34:56|
+--------+
```

Note that a unix timestamp is stored as the number of seconds since 00:00:00, 1 January 1970.  If you try to convert a time with millisecond accuracy to a timestamp, you will lose the millisecond part of the time.  For times including milliseconds, you will need to use a different approach.

Comment: One issue  it does not give correct time example 131717 got converted to 12:35:17, where as it should be 13:17:17

Comment: Can you post some code or the results of `printSchema` on your input `DataFrame`?  On my machine the 131717 conversion works correctly.

Comment: Hi Jermy, Just a followup question on this what if I need to include milliseconds as well, I tried adding SS but it did not give appropriate result, so 13345607 should return 13:34:56:07. Can you please help